# Marketing cloud / Exact target API choice(s)

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is the `FuelSDK-Java` (http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/FuelSDK-Java/), being actively maintained?  I noticed the primary contributor (Ian Murdock) unfortunately passed away, so I’m a little concerned about the codes ongoing maintenance given that he appeared to be the main contributor.  The way this API is described is a wrapper around both the REST and SOAP API’s, so that’s what I have been primarily trying to use.

Looking at the Issues log on GitHub, there are 16 open issues, and 8 of them are assigned to Ian.

Given that they are listed off of the official Salesforce documentation pages (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/), I hope that these are being maintained.

Comment: I thought Ian had already left salesforce and moved on to Docker anyways.

Comment: It was announced this month that Ian [committed suicide](http://money.cnn.com/2016/07/06/technology/ian-murdock-suicide/). Such sad news. I have only heard great things about about Ian from those who worked with him.

Answer (score 0):

You can see from the GitHub commits which ones are actively being maintained.

- [FuelSDK-CSharp](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp)
- [FuelSDK-Java](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Java)
- [FuelSDK-PHP](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP)
- [FuelSDK-Python](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python)
- [FuelSDK-Ruby](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Ruby)

Most people just fork the SDKs and modify them as needed.  Or like our team did, write their own.

The truth should be in the API documentation for the Objects and Methods.  The SDKs are simply abstract tools to make the development faster.